# Updating a null row without anything unique for that row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
[Receipt]   [Date]     [Barcode]    [Quantity]  [Supplier]  [DeliveryID]
  0001    01/01/2000    0000001         5        Grocery        NULL
  0001    01/01/2000    0000002         7        Grocery        NULL
  0001    01/01/2000    0000571         2        Grocery        NULL
  0002    01/01/2000    0000041         5         Grocey        NULL
  0002    01/01/2000    0000701        10         Grocey        NULL
  0003    01/01/2000    0000001         9        Groceri        NULL
```

> What can I do to put an incrementing value to the `DeliveryID`?

As you can see, there is nothing unique that can be used to distinguish a row from another row. There is a large chance that a similar data like any of those rows may be entered again.

Unfortunately, I cannot delete the table and create a new one for the sake of the new column.

I tried counting all the `null` rows first,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount FROM dbo.Delivery WHERE DeliveryID IS NULL
```

And create a `for` loop to update.

But I realized that after the first loop, all `null` will be replaced by `1`, instead of updating each row per loop.

I have thought of combining the `Receipt` and `Supplier` to become a unique value, but as I said earlier, there's a chance that a similar data may be entered, thus creating a duplicate row, losing the uniqueness of the row

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: As per your example, each row is unique, just need to use all the columns as a where-clause. If not then maybe turn use databases auto-increment feature and do this in the db. Might be doable.

Comment: Isn't Receipt+Date+Barcode unique combination ?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MSSQL

Comment: @Esko I would do that, unfortunately I just added the `DeliveryID` via `ALTER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a row_number

```
with D as
(
    select Receipt, Date, Barcode, DeliveryID, row_number() over(order by receipt , Date, Barcode) as rn
    from delivery
    )

update D
set DeliveryID = rn
where DeliveryID is null
```

You can even partition by receipt to provide a per-line within the receipt group:

```
with D as
(
    select Receipt, Date, Barcode, DeliveryID, row_number() over(partition by receipt order by Date, Barcode) as rn
    from delivery
    )

update D
set DeliveryID = rn
where DeliveryID is null
```

Comment: This is nice. It added a unique value even if the `DeliveryID` is `nvarchar`. How did the `row_number()` provide the number?

Comment: It basically orders the rows within the "window" (the `over` section), but applies on a line by line basis. Plus, integers will inherently convert to varchar in SQL server. For more info, have a search for "SQL SERVER WINDOW FUNCTIONS"

Answer (score 1):

You could use these columns:

```
[Receipt]   [Date]     [Barcode]    [Quantity]
```

as a PrimaryKey so you can identify the rows you need.

Or for the column [Delivery ID] you could use the IDENTITY function:

- https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/27/sql-server-how-to-an-add-identity-column-to-table-in-sql-server/
- http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/identity-function-439.aspx

Comment: Although I'm tempted to use `IDENTITY`, I noticed before that after some days had passed, instead of going `4` from `1`, `2`, `3`, it goes something like `1002` or so

Comment: In the end, I tried the code in the first link. As long as it gives me a unique value, I can live with whatever it gives

Answer (score 0):

Add column with identity that would help you

like

```
 alter table tableName add  DeliveryID int Identity(1,1)
```